# Mac alternative for Subtitle Edit?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, video, subtitle

I'm a video producer and our company recently moved to Mac due to the efficiency of the M1 chip. I used to work with subtitles and translate them using a "Windows only" software named "Subtitle Edit". it has the option to create, edit and translate text, and supports many formats. I was pretty surprised to figure out Mac doesn't have anything that does the same thing... do you guys know any subtitle edit software that's actually good?
Video is needed to be played during the editing... I'm willing to pay for an alternative so price is not an issue

Comment: This belongs on the Software Recommendations stack exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtitle editor for OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/subtitle-editor-for-osx) Also https://www.videoproc.com/video-editor/best-subtitle-editor.htm